# copy web site confiuration from IIS6 to IIS7 on a remote server

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, msdeploy

Hellp
I have to copy all web sites on a windows 2003 box ( IIS 6 ) to a windows 2008 ( IIS7.5).
there are about 1000 sites. I copy all data and content manually but what can I do for IIS configuration :
I test several msdeply command but all of report some errors.
the remote server is not accessible from old one.

how can I do this or whats a correct comand to copy configuration all site on one 116 web server to II7 web server?

best reagrds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Deploy is probably the best one, if you cannot access it you could sync to a package and then apply the package on the server.
If you get errors you can post them in here http://forums.iis.net/1144.aspx and you will get help on them.